# Jquery Live and Draggable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, live

I am binding a click event to an image using Jquery Live binding.  The first time I click on the image the simplemodal popup launches and draggable works fine.  After that, the simplemodal popup still launches and the draggable item will not drag.  Any ideas?

Code of Live Click Event:

```
$("table tr td img:not(.Help)").live("click", function(){

    $("#draggable").draggable({
        containment: 'parent',
        drag: function(e, ui){
            alert("dragging");
        }
    });

    $("#modal").modal({
        onShow: function(){
            $("html").css("overflow", "hidden");
        },
        onClose: function(){
            $("html").css("overflow", "auto");
            $("table tr td img").live("click", function(){});
            $.modal.close();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Suggestion: Edit your post, select your code, and click the Code Sample button above the text area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case anyone looks for this in the future the solution was to put the "draggable" code in the onShow callback.

```
$("table tr td img:not(.Help)").live("click", function(){ 

    $("#modal").modal({ 
        onShow: function(){
             $("#draggable").draggable({ 
                containment: 'parent', 
                drag: function(e, ui){ 
                    alert("dragging"); 
                } 
            });  
            $("html").css("overflow", "hidden"); 
        }, 
        onClose: function(){ 
            $("html").css("overflow", "auto"); 
            $("table tr td img").live("click", function(){}); 
            $.modal.close(); 
        } 
    }); 
});
```